# Chronometer Control - cambiar Tick Interval en ejecución web

Tags: genexus

En GX17 U3 .net estoy utilizando el Chronometer Control (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?25058,Chronometer+Control) como indica la documentación de Genexus, ya que a partir de la versión 16 el Timer User Control quedó deprecado (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8311,Timer+User+Control).

En el Timer User Control podía setear el intervalo de tiempo en el cual hacía elapsed en ejecución, por ejemplo en el evento start (propiedad Interval) y para el mismo se utiliza un parámetro en el sistema. Utilizando el Chronometer Control hay una propiedad a nivel Web Panel (Tick Interval), pero no me deja cambiar la misma en ejecución.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para asignar esta propiedad en ejecución, como hacía con el UC que quedó deprecado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respuesta del soporte de GX:

"*Tenemos un WA para este caso:
Editar el archivo: **UserControls\SDChronometer\PropertiesDefinition.xml**. Cerrar y abrir GX.
En dicho archivo, sacando la linea "DesignTime" (la deje separada en el ejemplo), te va dejar asignar la Propiedad en Runtime en el Start.*"

```
<Prop>
<Id>TickInterval</Id>
<Name>TickInterval</Name>
<Description>Indicates the Tick event frecuency in seconds.</Description>
<Type>Integer</Type>
<Default>1</Default>
<Metadata>
<Value name='FlagControlInfoProp'></Value>

<Value name="FlagScope">DesignTime</Value> -- Ésta es la línea que hay que quitar --

</Metadata>
</Prop>
```